# is it right to use batcher.drawSprite to draw all images in game?

Tags: java, android, image

I'm developing a game and use batcher.drawSprite method to draw all images in the game (background and all characters)

```
in assets.java :
    charAtlas = new Texture(game, "charAtlas.png");
    charEnemy = new TextureRegion(charAtlas, 0,0,250,300);

in worldGame.java :
   batcher.beginBatch(Assets.charAtlas);  // set atlas
   batcher.drawSprite(130, 628, 120,140, Assets.charEnemy);  
        //assets.charEnemy
```

is it right to use this method in all condition ? 
I have 3 atlas in game , i even use 2048x2048 atlas size so i can include all my images in there..

However, the image looks blurry in game (Tested in galaxy note, tab, and galaxy young). looks at the code above, i even have the enemy char take size in my atlas as much as 250x300 , it's not make sense that it'll look blurry as i only draw it in 120x140.

note : i use no layout (i mean no layout file in res folder) .. i use drawsprite to draw all image (Character,menu, button, etc).. 
update :
I tried to use character image files from other game that i unzipped, when i run the app, it also looks blurry and jagged. while in the original game, it's so smooth and sharp.  why is that ?

Comment: so long and still no answer, pity stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your code, you might use scaledbitmap  , see if you can set like this.

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);
```